# Staircase algorithm speed improvement

Tags: python

There is inreger **`a`** which represents the amount of stairs. Each number in list `b` represents the amount of stairs you can jump from current stair. You need to find out if it is possible to get from first to last stair.

**Example of input:**

case a)

```
8
1 3 0 0 2 0 1 1
```

case b)

```
3
0 1 1
```

**Example of output:**

case a)

```
True
```

case b)

```
False
```

I managed to create a code which works, but exceeds the time limit. All numbers are positive and have int type. Could you give me an idea how to improve my algorithm (if you can name it so).

My code:

```
a = int(input())
b = list(map(int, input().split()))

flag = True
count = 0
for i in range(a):
    if b[i] > 0:
        if count != 0:
            position = i - count - 1
            if b[position] <= count:
                flag = False
                break
            count = 0
    elif b[i] == 0:
        if i == 0:
            flag = False
            break
        else:
            count += 1

print(flag)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `itertools.accumulate` https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=accumulate#itertools.accumulate or manually iterate through you list subtracting from `a` till you reach 0.